# How to take unbuffered input in c++ (i.e without hitting enter key)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to take comma delimited input from the user so that without pressing enter key,the input is accepted.

Comment: What have you tried? Edit the question to add some code and give more info to make us easy to help you. A minimal example of what you tried helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible in a portable manner in pure C++, because it depends too much on the terminal used that may be connected with stdin (they are usually line buffered). You can, try to use `getchar()` or `getline()` and try to tweak your code based on your requirement.